# Can't npm install express

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I can't install Express through npm install express. Actually I get an error if it try to install  the dev dependency called content-type. https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-type

I tried to install the content-type package, it doesn't work. Here is the error:

```
60 error path C:\Users\kv\workspace\test\node_modules\content-type
61 error code ENOENT
62 error errno -4058
63 error syscall rename
64 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\kv\workspace\test\node_modules\content-type' -> 'C:\Users\kv\workspace\test\node_modules\.content-type.DELETE'
65 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I use Windows 7 64 bit. I already installed Express once, 1 week ago, worked well.

Here is the full log file: https://pastebin.com/7S4MYLed

Does someone knows this issue and how to solve it? I already tried to reinstall Node.js/npm. I also cleared the cache and restarted my computer.

Comment: Have you tried to remove node_modules folder and re-install it again ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your node_module file and run npm install command again. Hope this will work

Comment: Have you tried the instruction mention in line no. 64 in your error code  and can you show us the full error code?

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening because your npm directory has not been initialised.
Use:

> npm init

to initialize the directory. Then use

> npm install

to install dependencies. Also check package.json for dependencies.

Another workaround can be installing [express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html).